# Raise errors and display traceback messages from panel dashboards

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews, pyviz, holoviz

When I link widget updates to a function and display the output in a panel, errors that result from updating the widget to a value that the function cannot handle, cause the function to fail silently instead of terminating the execution of the panel and displaying a traceback.

In the following example, `x` is undefined so when the slider is dragged to `5`, the function fails silently and the output value is not updated. If the slider start value is set to `5`, the function will raise a `NameError` as expected and the panel will not be initialized.

```
import panel as pn

pn.extension()
int_slider = pn.widgets.IntSlider(
    name='Integer Slider', value=1, end=5)

@pn.depends(int_slider.param.value, watch=True)
def print_slider_value(slider_value):
    if slider_value <= 4:
        return slider_value
    else:
        return slider_value * x

pn.Column(int_slider, print_slider_value) #.app('localhost:8888')
```

I would like errors to be raised when they result from a widget value change, so that it is clear when an error has occured and what happened from the traceback. How can I achieve this with panel? (I saw [this issue](https://github.com/pyviz/panel/issues/163) on debugging mode with pipelines, but couldn't find anything similar for panels).

I have been trying this in the JupyterLab notebook with the following packages versions

```
bokeh       1.2.0
panel       0.6.0
param       1.9.1
IPython     6.5.0
jupyter_client  5.2.3
jupyter_core    4.4.0
jupyterlab  1.0.2
notebook    5.6.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Panel v0.14.0 update

As of version [0.14.0](https://github.com/holoviz/panel/releases/tag/v0.14.0), you can also plug in a [simple exception_handler](https://blog.holoviz.org/panel_0.14.html#Simpler-Exception-Handling), to show notifications on the client side.

e.g.

```py
import logging
import panel as pn

def exception_handler(ex):
    logging.error("Error", exc_info=ex)
    pn.state.notifications.error('Error: %s' % ex)

pn.extension(exception_handler=exception_handler, notifications=True)
```

---

As of version [0.13.0](https://github.com/holoviz/panel/releases/tag/v0.13.0), you can get this functionality out of the box via the [Debugging widget](https://panel.holoviz.org/reference/widgets/Debugger.html).

e.g.

```py
logger = logging.getLogger('panel.myapp')

debug_info = pn.widgets.Debugger(
  name='Debugger info level', 
  level=logging.INFO, 
  sizing_mode='stretch_both',
  # comment this line out to get all panel errors
  logger_names=['panel.myapp'] 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I [asked this question on the panel issue tracker](https://github.com/pyviz/panel/issues/163) and received the response that the errors can be seen in the JS console. On Firefox, you can open this with `Ctrl-Shift-k` or right click -> inspect element -> console. In Chrome it is `Ctrl-Shift-c` or right click -> inspect -> console.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57376599/2166823) shows how to embed the console in a div so that it can be displayed together with other elements directly in the app.

Comment: While this works well, I am still interested for a way to see the error messages directly in the notebook or the app itself (the latter would be especially useful when distributing the application).

Comment: The terminal widget is a good fit to display log info (e.g. [stdout](https://panel.holoviz.org/reference/widgets/Terminal.html#writing-stdout-to-the-terminal)), although I'm not clear _how_ to wire up a 'catchall' to ensure any trace info is propagated to the client in the case of an exception..

Comment: Update - [found it!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72167334/1177832)

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I had a similar issue and came up with a "widget" solution to this problem.  The idea is you capture the error, format it as an html and then output the error into a widget that is already inside the dashboard.

In the example below you can see that I have a dashboard that will return almost any string you type into it after submit is pressed,  the exception is the string "roger".  If "roger" is entered into the dashboard a traceback will be presented to the user directly in the notebook/ Panel app itself.

```
import panel as pn
import traceback as tb
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import Python3TracebackLexer
from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter
pn.extension()

toggle = pn.widgets.Toggle(name='Press Here')
field = pn.widgets.TextInput(placeholder='Type something here . . .', visible=False)
submit = pn.widgets.Button(name='Submit', button_type='primary', visible=False)
out = pn.widgets.StaticText(value='orginal output')

def extract_format_tb_html(e):
    traceback_str = ''.join(tb.format_exception(None, e, e.__traceback__))
    return highlight(traceback_str, Python3TracebackLexer(), HtmlFormatter(noclasses=True))

def myfunc(x):
    if x != 'roger':
        out.value = field.value
    else:
        raise

def test(event):
    try:
        myfunc(field.value)
    except Exception as e:
        out.value = extract_format_tb_html(e)

def callback(target, event):
    if event.new:
        target.visible=True
    else:
        target.visible=False

toggle.link(field, callbacks={'value': callback})
toggle.link(submit, callbacks={'value': callback})
submit.on_click(test)

widget_row = pn.Row(toggle, field, submit)
dashboard = pn.Column(widget_row, out)

dashboard
```

The result is:

[image]